# What's a good approach to disabling functionality that's not supported?

Tags: design-patterns, ios, game-center

I suppose this question is language-agnostic, tho I'm asking it in regards to building an iPhone app that uses the new Game Center API, but please feel free to answer in general software engineering terms.

I'm building a game for the iPhone that takes advantage of the new Game Center capabilities (i.e. Auto-matching, leaderboards, achievements, etc.), but I want to write the game so that it works on all iPhones, including those that don't have Game Center installed and cannot make use of the Game Center capabilities.  To do this, Apple recommends the approach...

***"We'd recommend making one version of the app which dynamically detects whether Game Center is available and uses it (or not) based on that."***

With my current level of programming, the simple approach I would take to implementing this would be to check if whether or not Game Center is available and set a simple boolean flag accordingly.  Then use that flag to control the flow of execution throughout the software.  I'm sure I could make that work, but because I enjoy learning and enjoy programming, I was wondering if there's a better approach or design pattern for disabling blocks of functionality that aren't supported, along with controlling the flow of execution.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Game Kit code examples on Apple's dev site.  They implement a GameCenterManager class that will work well for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

What you generally use in these cases is called the [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). In your case, you'd build a wrapper for the functions of the game center you use in your app, and then two implementations -- one which probably does little more than proxy calls to the game center and another which returns canned answers as required.

I will note that I've never done any iOS/objective C programming so I have no idea how one would actually implement this properly in that environment.

Comment: You would implement it exactly as you describe :) more specifically, have a wrapper class/object that all gamecenter calls go through. The class checks if the APIs are actually available, and responds appropriately, and the rest of the app can be agnostic to Game Center detection. If the gamecenter API later changes, only need to change it in one place in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I typically test for Game Center support with a simple C-style function that extends Apple's recommended method. This adds a device test for iPod Touch 1st Gen and 3G models, since Apple's code does not account for those devices.

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

BOOL isGameCenterAvailable()
{
    // Check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API.
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

    // The device must be running running iOS 4.1 or later.
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

    // 1st Gen iPod and 3G don't support Game Center
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *theModel = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([theModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"] ||
        [theModel isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}
```

Usage is as simple as

```
if (isGameCenterAvailable())
{
    // display game center UI
}
```